# How to create and align a base R Barplot with an abline regression line?

Tags: r, regression, bar-chart, linear-regression

I am trying to make a bar plot using base R code along with a linear fit using abline, but it seems like I am not getting the right results when using abline. At least, when looking at the regression line, and comparing it with drawing some lines using the predicted model it is way off:

```
df <- data.frame(year = c(2018,2019,2020), PWI = c(64.7,71.3,75.2))
barplot(PWI~year, data = df, ylim = c(0,100))
text(x,y+2,labels=as.character(as.matrix(round(df,1))))

abline(lm(PWI~I(year-2018)), lty = "dashed", col = "red")
```

[image: Image showing the base R approach where abline does not align]

How do I get abline to align with the barplot?

For the record, I'm interested in a base R approach with a line behaving like abline. It can be done in ggplot by:

```
coeff <- coefficients(lm(PWI~year, data = df))
ggplot(df,aes(year,PWI)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  geom_abline(intercept = coeff[1], slope = coeff[2])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the output of barplot in a variable. It contains the center of every bar

```
out <- barplot(PWI~year, data = df, ylim = c(0,100))
abline(lm(PWI~I(out), data = df), lty = "dashed", col = "red")
```

Comment: Simple and efficient!

Answer (score 1):

So what's happening here is that `barplot` is doing some magic for the x-coordinates that isn't the same for abline.

```r
df <- data.frame(year = c(2018,2019,2020), PWI = c(64.7,71.3,75.2))

bp <- barplot(PWI~year, data = df, ylim = c(0,100))
print(bp)
     [,1]
[1,]  0.7
[2,]  1.9
[3,]  3.1
```

the values here are the actual x-coordinates used by barplot. We can draw the correct abline like so:

```r
df <- data.frame(year = c(2018,2019,2020), PWI = c(64.7,71.3,75.2))
bp <- barplot(PWI~year, data = df, ylim = c(0,100))
text(x,y+2,labels=as.character(as.matrix(round(df,1))))

fit <- lm(PWI~I(year-2018), data = df)

# manually compute the predictions 
ycoords <- predict(fit)

lines(bp, ycoords, col = 3, lty = 3)
points(bp, ycoords, col = 3, lty = 3)
```

which gives me:

[image]

the green line is now where it should be.

edit: Note that barplot is probably turning year into a factor (just change 2020 to 3000 in your example). So the figure might skew the relation in the data if you're plotting something at varying intervals.

Comment: That is all fine, however it is not the abline as you see in my question. I've already done done it with lines (the black dashed line shown in the picture), using `x <- barplot(PWI ~ year, data = df) yval <- predict.lm(reg_pwi, yyy)
lines(x = x, y = yval, lty = "dashed")` that was how I investigated what was wrong in the first place.

Comment: There's no substantial difference between the code in your comment and the one in my answer. Note, however, that https://stackoverflow.com/a/63616223/4917834 is not regressing the years on PWI but instead it regresses the centers of the bins on PWI. That's perfectly fine for a figure though.

Comment: Which was maybe that technical insight that I needed. The centers on the bins. Thanks!